# What does the #{} within a ruby string actually do?

Tags: ruby, string

As the question asks, is it just calling `to_s` on the return value of the embedded expression?

Like this?

```
"1, 2, #{1 + 2}" == "1, 2, " + 3.to_s
```

Or is there more going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it calls `to_s` on the result of the expression. Try it.

```
:001> class Monkey
:002>   def to_s
:003>     "monkey"
:004>     end
:005>   end
 => nil 
:006> m = Monkey.new
 => monkey
:007> "I am a #{m}"
 => "I am a monkey"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's really just a place-holder saying, "Hey, here we have some ruby code that needs to be evaluated and cast as a string." If you are familiar with C-style languages at all, it is pretty much the same thing as:

```
printf("1, 2, %d", 1+2);
```